# how can i compare two Lists

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There are two Lists, i want to compare 
these lists having same values or not
how can i do this please suggest

```
List<WebElement> Gender=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*@id='MyMember_GenderId']"));
int genderval=Gender.size();
System.out.println(genderval);
for(WebElement G : Gender ) {
    System.out.println("Gender is :"+G.getText());
}
List<WebElement> Mstatus=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MyMember_MaritalStatusId']"));
int statusval=Mstatus.size();
System.out.println(statusval);
for(WebElement text : Mstatus ) {
    System.out.println("Gender is :"+text.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`containsAll`** function. Like for your case you can do that get text of Gender in a String list and Mstatus in another list i.e.

```
List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement G : Gender ) {
    genderList.add(G.getText());
}
List<String> mstatusList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (WebElement G : Mstatus) {
    mstatusList.add(G.getText());
}
System.out.println(mstatusList.containsAll(genderList));
```

**containsAll** will check for all the elements of provided **Collection**.

Comment: @user3729477: If the above answer has helped you, please consider it marking as answer. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just an alternative way to assert if two lists are equal or not.
As per **@Vivek**, get the lists of texts, and say the lists that you get after retrieving the texts are: **genderList** and **mstatusList**.

You can use the below code to assert the two lists, too:

```
try{
    Assert.assertEquals(genderList, mstatusList);
    System.out.println("Equal lists");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Lists are not equal. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

**NOTE:** You need to import the **Assert class** using **import junit.framework.Assert;** (assuming you are working on a junit framework, that is.)

Comment: its not a good practice to catch an error. And instead of using JUnit assert its better to use TestNG SoftAssert. Hope am right in this suggestion. :)

Comment: You might be actually very right. But, thing is, I haven't worked on TestNG framework yet. Hence, the above suggestion (related to junit.).. :)
On another note, here catching error ensures the execution keeps moving forward, not halt and exit. It actually depends on the person , if he/she wants to catch the error(s) and move on, or halt the execution and quit when error(s), like this, are found.